# Create cron job in PHP

Tags: cron

Is there a way I can create a cron job in php to be run by a specific user. By default it runs as wwww-data and this doesn't work. Can I change the user and run it ? The following is what I am doing. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

```
shell_exec('(crontab -u username -l 2>/dev/null; echo "* * * * * /usr/bin/php filename.php") | crontab -');
```

Answer (score 0):

There're `/etc/cron.XXX/` folders nowadays (i.e.  `cron.daily`, `cron.hourly` etc) where you can simply drop your job as new file w/o bothering other config files.

Comment: The content of those folders should not be writeable to the php process, as this cronjobs running as root

Comment: The cron command would be dynamically created within the php file depending on the input from user(minute, hour, day, month, week). So I will need the cronjob to be created from within the php file.

Answer (score 0):

Your command seems to be wrong.

`echo "* * * * * /usr/bin/php filename.php" | crontab -` is enoguh because `crontab` *maintains crontab files for individual users*. So if you launch it as `www-data` it will be created an entry for `www-data` user.

Hope it will help!

Comment: But he don't want www-data

Comment: Since he said that over `www-data` user the cronjob wasn't working I assumed that it was due to the `command` syntax error. This because he can't do it without www-data. To be more specific he can, but the permissions will be the same, this means no writing permissions on /etc/ at all.

Comment: By default it considers user as www-data in ubuntu apache. I want to change it to current user.Below is the error message. 
    You (www-data) are not allowed to use this program (crontab)

Comment: What do you mean by current user? If you didn't touch any config php should be running as `www-data` user. If the script says that you're not allowed to use crontab try to take a look at `/etc/cron.allow` and add `www-data` user.